# undefined method for Questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the error `` undefined method `questions' for nil:NilClass `` when viewing different profiles. I am not seeing why this is an undefined method. Anyone have a clue what I did not do correct?

Logs:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `questions' for nil:NilClass): 
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:80:in `show'
```

Users Controller:

```
     def show
        @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is letting you know that the **@user** variable is not being set. Check your *before_action/before_filter or whatever is setting that variable* to make sure it is not failing.

Comment: that variable is fine, as it's `@user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])`

Comment: where is the filter calling it ? it's definitely returning nil, so check your params..

Comment: @user is definitely nil. Toss in a byebug to diagnose.

Comment: Your right on the issue, however there is a bug within the app. It was not recognizing the `username`, however after a few pushes of trying to fix it, I went back to `@user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])` and it magically started working again lol. For now all pages work, but there is apparently something else going on that I need to catch.